# How to get posts for specific categories in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am wondering if there is a function in Wordpress where I can get all the posts in specific cateogires and order them according to category so each category would have an array of posts that belong to it.

I tried to us get_posts function but with no luck:

```
$args      = array(
'numberposts' => 15,
'category' => '161,165,166,1',
);
$postslist = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put ID of WP post and with functon get_post for retrieving post data as array.

```
<?php
    $my_id = 7;
    $post_id_7 = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
    $title = $post_id_7['post_title'];
?>
```

Full reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

If you want get a posts by category id use:

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
$cats = array();

foreach($post_categories as $c){
    $cat = get_category( $c );
    $cats[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
}
```

or dump with full data:

```
   var_dump($cat);
```

Comment: This loads specific posts by ID, not the posts for specific categories. Your second example gets the categories for a post id, bu the original question is looking for the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `query_posts` and the `category__in` or `category__and` argument - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

```
$args = array( 'category__in' => array(161,165,166,1), 'posts_per_page' => 15 );
query_posts( $args );
while (have_posts()): the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;
```